# Does capitalization affect variables within a function block in golang?

Tags: variables, go, scopes

If I declare a variable or parameter in a function, does capitalization have any affect or meaning?

Obviously for methods and variables outside of functions it exports them, but what about the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables declared inside a function block are always private, or unexported.
Capitalization has no effects in this case.

Comment: To be more precise, it's not that they're unexported - "exporting" a local variable in a function has no meaning (how would you even reference it from outside the function?). This has nothing to do with exporting, but rather with [scoping](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). Only identifiers with package scope can be referenced from outside their scope, and then only if they are exported.